# A generic UIPickerView+UITextField function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a function called

```
`createSpinner(params: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> UITextField`
```

which will take parameters like height, width and return a UITextField in which there will be a UIPickerView attached. Also, I am trying to find a way to integrate even the controllers in it.

Till now I have created the UITextfield in the function and also added a `dropdown` button to the right of the UITextField. Then I have initialized a UIPickerView in the function and added it to the `inputView` of the UITextField instance.

Now the problem I am facing is, when the user touches the `dropdown`, I want to call a function using `addTarget` to bring up the UIPickerView instance. Where should I implement the `action:` of `addTarget` and what should the `target` in `addTarget` be?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to link those actions. The first is to hook up to the UITextFieldDelegate where you can use textFieldDidStartEditing or you can fake the UITextField by creating a UIButton where you can hook up to various UIControlEvents.

Comment: What if I want to use my function to create 2 input spinners in the same view?

Comment: Subclass the UITextField and add those spinners as subviews?